# Check if any arrays in object contain empty values

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `newEntries` which has 2 entries so far:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {name: "test", website: "", sector: "", house: ""}
1: {name: "", website: "", sector: "", house: ""}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

As it is visible, currently only one field of one index is filled. I need to return `true` if all the fields for all elements are filled and `false` otherwise.

How can I do so in javascript?

Comment: It asks about a single string, and this is about an object array with sting values. Quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using combo of `.every` and `.some` will work for us :-

```js
const array1 = [
{name: "test", website: "fdf", sector: "fdf", house: "fdf"},
{name: "fds", website: "fsd", sector: "fds", house: "fsdf"}]

const array2 = [
{name: "test", website: "", sector: "fdf", house: "fdf"},
{name: "fds", website: "fsd", sector: "fds", house: "fsdf"}]


function checkArray(array){
  return array.every(item => 
    !Object.values(item).some(value => value === "")
  );
}

console.log(checkArray(array1));
console.log(checkArray(array2));
```

Comment: Actually, this is very much the same as the two `.every`'s you've had before the edit. Both are correct. (*There are no such value, that is an empty string* = *All values are **not** equal to an empty string*)

Comment: @FZs in the `some` bit, I think I would skip iterating through rest of the object values as soon as `value===""` making this approach better ? Or am I wrong in assuming that ?

Comment: So would it be with the `.every`. `.some` is really just an inverted `.every`...

Comment: So even if a `.some` condition matches, the subsequent callbacks are still performed nevertheless ?

Comment: According to JS docs: The `some()` method executes the callback `function` once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callback returns a `truthy` value. 
And the `every` method executes the provided callback `function` once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callback returns a `falsy` value.

Comment: Using `some` indeeed makes the operation way faster (especially if the object gets bigger)
I've created a jsbench so everbody can try out himself: https://jsbench.me/4xkm33t6pw/1

Comment: @LakshyaThakur No, both **do** short-circuit. `.some` short-circuits on `true`, while `.every` short-circuits on `false`.

Comment: @FZs So it depends on the data distribution of the array. If every property of object was filled, the performance benchmarks will be in favour of every. Actually `every` + `some` seems to hit the sweet spot.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Because one's inverted and the other is not, it doesn't even depend on the data distribution, they are **the same**. Benchmarks really seem to favor `every`+`some`, but it is probably an implementation/optimisation thing in the underlying engine, not in the code itself.

Answer (score 4):

Using `.some`:

```
const filled = !(arr.some(obj => Object.values(obj).some(v => !v)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop thru' all array items and all fields with a flag to check:

```js
var newEntries = [
    {name: "test", website: "", sector: "", house: ""},
    {name: "",     website: "", sector: "", house: ""}
];

for (let i=0; i<newEntries.length; i++){
    let entry     = newEntries[i];
    let allFilled = true;

    for (let field in entry)
        if (entry[field]==""){
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }

    if (allFilled)
        console.log(entry);
}
```

Comment: That would work but that's what some/every function were introduced for

Comment: yeah, that `every` function is neat

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array, and then for each object within it, loop over its properties. If they're empty, return false.
Otherwise, it'll get to the end and return true. :)

```
function checkAll() {
    for (let entry of newEntries) {
        for (let property in entry)
            if(entry[property] === "") return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi this is the best way:

```js
var newEntries = [
    {name: "test", website: "", sector: "", house: ""},
    {name: "",     website: "", sector: "", house: ""}
];

let result = true;

for (let i=0; i<newEntries.length; i++){
    let data = newEntries[i];
    let t = Object.values(data).some(val => val);
    if (!t) {
        result = false;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Actually, no, this isn't the best way. It doesn't even work if only the half of an object's properties are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the items

```
        var newEntries = [
                {name: "test", website: "", sector: "", house: ""},
                {name: "",     website: "", sector: "", house: ""}
            ];
            newEntries.forEach(myFunction);
            function myFunction(item) {
            if (array === undefined || array.length == 0) {
              return false;
            }
            else{
            return true;
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{a:1,b:"",c:"bhj"},{a:1,b:"hgh",c:"bhj"}]
var result = arr.filter(a => a.a != "" && a.b != ""&& a.c != "");
if(result.length===arr.length){
  console.log(true)
}else{
 console.log(false)}
```